# Date duplicates: Adding a counter for a specific row on today's date (VBA/Qlik Sense)

Tags: vba, excel, date, qliksense

I recently wrote a fairly simple bit of VBA code so that I can keep long-term track of what I am wearing each day. For this I made a Macro connected to a Command Button, and it looks like the following:

```
    Private Sub WearingToday_Click()

      Dim NextCol As Long
      NextCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
      Cells(1, NextCol).Value = Date
      Cells(ActiveCell.Row, NextCol).Value = "1"

    End Sub
```

The code simply adds today's date on the next available column, under which it adds the number "1" on the row which I've chosen.

My problem is, though, that if I activate the macro more than once a day, the date serial number of the second activation will have an additional 1 in the end, giving me a date corresponding to the year 3000-something. To make it clearer: I have worn two things on November 20th, which gives two adjacent columns with the same date; but only the first column of these dates shows the correct serial number.

I might mention that I'm importing the data into Qlik Sense, where I later will do some visualisations. I see the date serial numbers upon storing the data as a QVD-file and looking at it from QViewer.

The interesting thing is that the string representation of both serial numbers -- in the Excel spreadsheet -- is correct. As such, I am not sure if the problem indeed only exists as a consequence of the transition from .xlsm to .qvd, or if it is there from the beginning.

I hope I have been clear with my issue and that someone will be able to help me fix this, or at least make me understand what possibilites I have going forward.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will check to see if the last column heading is already today's date and, if so, just update the same column:

```
Private Sub WearingToday_Click()

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Cells(1, LastCol).Value2 < Date Then
        LastCol = LastCol + 1
        Cells(1, LastCol).Value = Date
    End If
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, LastCol).Value = 1

End Sub
```

I suspect that your export to Qlik Sense is being confused by having two columns with the same header (i.e. the date), and it might just be appending a "1" to the second header to make each header unique.  But I have never heard of, or seen, Qlik Sense so I can't be sure.  If that **is** the cause of the weird behaviour in Qlik Sense, then ensuring you don't have duplicate headers should make your problems disappear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I believe, as you say, that QS gets confused due to the headers not being unique. The code also works, so now each header is a unique date, and many rows beneath that date can now get a count.

However, does the code work as before as well? I mean, if LastCol is NOT the same date as today, will it add today's date to the adjacent header? I am a novice to VBA, that's why I am not completely certain. 

Thanks again.

Comment: @DrilonPollozhani Yes, the `If Cells(1, LastCol).Value2 < Date Then` tests to see whether the date in the last column is less than today's date and, if so, the bit within the `If` block adds today's date as a new column.